# Proof that the repeating block of digits in 1/x is at max x-1?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question is self-explanatory, I suppose. Example, the maximum number of digits in the repeating block of 1/17 is 16.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298844/period-of-repeating-decimals

Answer (score 3):

When you calculate the decimal value of $\frac{1}{x}$, you can only have x-1 possible remainders as you divide $1$ by $x$. You will only stop if you reach zero.

But if you reach the same number twice, then everything will start to repeat. Thus it has to repeat after at most x-1 divisions.

Comment: Right. Let me change that.